# Перенаправление трафика IPTABLES

Tags: iptables, debian

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 148.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 1123 -j DNAT --to-destination 144.x.x.x:80iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d 144.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 148.x.x.x
```

Трафик успешно перенаправляется, но ниже, в правилах я бы хотел ограничить кол-во подключений к порту, но он не собирается проверять обращения к порту после роутинга, как можно реализовать такое?

Смог спалить пересылку пакета в forward. Вопрос решен.

Comment: делайте лимит **до** DNAT/SNAT (или опишите что мешает это сделать)

Comment: Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Как я понимаю фильтры идут после нат

Comment: [как-то так на самом деле](http://igortiunov4unix.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/iptables-traffic-flow/)

Comment: Дак что делать то? как проверять все это дело?

Comment: Вообще есть программа клиентская она разных версий,есть программа, есть сервера на разных машинах. Есть одна тачка, на ней сидит программа, при подключение к порту, программа получает версию клиента и соответственно заносит с set список, который с помощью iptables перенаправляет ее на соответствующий сервер. Мне нужно ограничить кол-во соединений в минуту, как сделать пока не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял то так

-A FORWARD -s 148.x.x.x -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 80 --connlimit-mask 32 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptLimFrTCP1: "

-A FORWARD -s 148.x.x.x -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 80 --connlimit-mask 32 -j DROP